# How to make Jar which includes DLL?

Tags: java, deployment, dll, jar, native

I have a Jar which fetches the DLL from some path which is specified in configuration file. 
I keep that configuration file at the location from where I am executing my application.
That DLL is also installed somewhere else.

Now I want to make my Jar which should consist of  (classes **&**) DLL.  I don't want to give any path because that configuration file may not be present.

How to proceed with this?  How to make jar and what changes do I need to do?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Comment: How are you packaging your JAR now? Do you have a handcrafted Ant script? Are you using the built in features of an IDE such as Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

If your app. has a GUI, the easy way to include native libraries on the run-time class-path of the application is to use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy it.  Here are how the resource sections of the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) launch file might look.

```
<resources >
    <j2se version="1.6+"/> 
    <!-- Supply this resource to all -->
    <jar href="ourapp.jar" size="100000" />
</resource>
<!-- Supply this resource to SunOS/sparc only -->
<resources os="SunOS" arch="sparc">
    <nativelib href="sunlibs.jar" size="250000" />
</resource>
<!-- Supply this resource to Windows only -->
<resources os="Windows">
    <nativelib href="winlibs.jar" size="300000" />
</resource>
```

JWS partitions the downloads, so Mac. and any non SunOS *nix get just 100,000 bytes of core Java.  SunOS gets a total download of 350,000 bytes, and Windows gets 400,000 bytes.  The application can then load the native using something like:

```
System.loadLibrary("ournative");
```

After that, the native should be loaded and ready for use in any OS for which a native was supplied.

Deployment via. JWS has a number of advantages, including:

- A cross-platform and convenient way to deploy natives.
- Partitioned download of the natives.
- Automatic update of application resources (classes, natives, etc..)
- Avoiding "DLL Hell" by way of the automatic updates.